# Nesting a KnockoutJS foreach loop

Tags: knockout.js

I am battling with knockout trying to get a nested foreach statement to render

I have a view model

```
var ViewModel = function (transactions) {
var self = this;
self.transactions = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(transactions, function (transaction) {
    return new Transaction(
        transaction.TransactionId,
        transaction.Items);
}));
```

My Model

```
var Transaction = function (TransactionId,Items)
{
var self = this;
self.transactionId = ko.observable(TransactionId);
self.items = ko.observableArray(Items);
```

I am bind the viewmodel in my pages view

```
  var viewModel = new ViewModel([{"TransactionId":1007,"Items":[{"ItemId":1,"Description":"123"}]}]);
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("process"));
```

A cutdown version of the html looks like

```
       <ul data-bind="foreach: transactions">
        <li>
            <div class="title" data-bind="text:transactionId"></div>
          <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
          <li>ABC</li>
          <ul>
         </li>
```

I Am not getting errors however my unordered list is not being rendered. Am I doing something obvious here that is wrong?

I have created a jsfiddle that replicates the issue. It can be found here...[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spnz/n8dQU/)

Comment: Looks fine, have you inspected the `items` property of `self.transactions` to ensure it has data? Also, which list isn't being rendered? `transaction`, `items`, or both?

Comment: Your code seems working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/VF7yw/. Can you maybe create a JSFIddle which shows your problem?

Comment: transaction is rendered ok, its the items that are not. @nemesv yes your jsfiddle is working.....I trimmed down my code so I will check to see what is different

Comment: I found this little piece of gold         <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre> the output is missing items. How do I figure out why items is not populated? The raw json shows the data

Comment: So what's the problem? You say it doesn't get rendered yet even the fiddle you posted clearly shows it's working as it should...